# Set TestCategory attribute for unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

I'm reading a tests collection from some data source. so I get a collection of objects including: testAssembly,testClass,testName and groupID per object.
I'm trying to find a way for each testName create Testcategory attribute and give him the groupID. evrey test can be in a different assemblly,solution or class
Thanks

example:
before:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_test()
{
  code....
}
```

after:

```
[TestCategory(groupID)]
[TestMethod]
public void Test_test()
{
  code....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your custom attribute. There is [a lot of material for this online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes).

Example (from link):

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class |  
                   System.AttributeTargets.Struct)  
]  
public class AuthorAttribute : System.Attribute  
{  
   private string name;  
   public double version;  

   public AuthorAttribute(string name)  
   {  
        this.name = name;  
        version = 1.0;  
   }  
}
```

Usage:

```
[Author("P. Ackerman", version = 1.1)]  
class SampleClass  
{  
    // P. Ackerman's code goes here...  
}
```

Comment: My question is not how to write an attribute.
What I asked is how I run on the list of tests and everyone adds the attribute when each test can sit in a different namespace or class assembly

Comment: @דודושטראוס oh, sorry, either question was not clear enough or I misinterpreted it. Either way... Are you aware of the concept of partial classes. That might be the answer to your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how partial classes can help me
There are some layers I need to go through...
1) how to read dll from my code( dll name = testAssembly.
2) find the spesific class in the dll (class name = testClass) .
3) find the spsific method in the class ( method = testName). 
4) add an attribute to the method.